# When developing the flutter plugin, Huawei obtained that the appId is empty, and the configuration file .json file should not be read

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

In the development of the flutter plugin,

I ca n't get the appId. I put the configuration file .json in the java module and example app directories, and the appId cannot be obtained. How can I solve it?

I encapsulated the sdk into the plugin and reported an error: appId is empty

getToken failed, com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135000: arguments invalid

Comment: Maybe you can use huawei officially released plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following steps
1. Place the json file in the assets directory of the Android layer. If not, create a new one and add the following code in AndroidManifest.xml and Application:

```
<application

android:name=".MyApplication"

…

>
```

…

public class MyApplication extends Application{

@Override

public void onCreate() {

```
   super.onCreate();
```

}

// TODO: Add the following code:

@Override

protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {

```
   super.attachBaseContext(context);

   AGConnectServicesConfig config = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(context);

   config.overlayWith(new LazyInputStream(context) {

       public InputStream get(Context context) {

           try {

               return context.getAssets().open("agconnect-services.json");

           } catch (IOException e) {

               return null;

           }

       }

   });
```

}

// TODO: End

}

2.You can obtaine App ID by the following code

```
String appId = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(this).getString("client/app_id");
```

If it still fails, please add tags under the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <meta-data 

        android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid" 

        android:value="appid=xxxxx"> 

    </meta-data>
```

Comment: Advice with these lines: <meta-data
    android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid"
    android:value="appid=111111111">
</meta-data>
helps me to resolve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The appId can be obtained by the following code:

```
String appId = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(this).getString("client/app_id");
```